# melt data frame and split values

Tags: r

I have the following data frame with measurements concatenated into a single column, separated by some delimiter:

```
df <- data.frame(v1=c(1,2), v2=c("a;b;c", "d;e;f"))
df
     v1 v2
  1  1  a;b;c
  2  2  d;e;f;g
```

I would like to melt/transforming it into the following format:

```
     v1 v2
  1  1  a
  2  1  b
  3  1  c
  4  2  d
  5  2  e
  6  2  f
  7  2  g
```

Is there an elegant solution?

Thx!

Comment: Are there always the same number of items in each row of V2 (3, in your example)?

Comment: no there can be 0..n values

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can split the strings with `strsplit`.

Split the strings in the second column:

```
splitted <- strsplit(as.character(df$v2), ";")
```

Create a new data frame:

```
data.frame(v1 = rep.int(df$v1, sapply(splitted, length)), v2 = unlist(splitted))
```

The result:

```
  v1 v2
1  1  a
2  1  b
3  1  c
4  2  d
5  2  e
6  2  f
```

Comment: This is the most efficient solution I have came across and doesn't require any packages.