# melt data table and split values

Tags: r, data.table

I have a column in a data table which is a list of comma separated values

```
dt = data.table( a = c('a','b','c'), b = c('xx,yy,zz','mm,nn','qq,rr,ss,tt'))
> dt
   a           b
1: a    xx,yy,zz
2: b       mm,nn
3: c qq,rr,ss,tt
```

I would like to transform it into a long format

```
   a  b
1: a xx
2: a yy
3: a zz
4: b mm
5: b nn
6: c qq
7: c rr
8: c ss
9: c tt
```

This question has been answered for a data frame [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13808553/melt-data-frame-and-split-values). I'm wondering if there is an elegant data table solution.

Comment: You can try `setnames(dt[, strsplit(b, ','), a], "V1", "b")[]`

Comment: You're too fast.  I was getting to your comment. I would have initially accepted your comment as the answer and for being first.  I think the accepted answer is cleaner.  Appreciate your quick response!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following will work for your example:

```
dt[, c(b=strsplit(b, ",")), by=a]
   a b
1: a xx
2: a yy
3: a zz
4: b mm
5: b nn
6: c qq
7: c rr
8: c ss
9: c tt
```

---

This method fails if the "by" variable is repeated as in

```
dt = data.table(a = c('a','b','c', 'a'),
                b = c('xx,yy,zz','mm,nn','qq,rr,ss,tt', 'zz,gg,tt'))
```

One robust solution in this situation can be had by using `paste` to collapse all observations with the same grouping variable (a) and feeding the result to the code above.

```
dt[, .(b=paste(b, collapse=",")), by=a][, c(b=strsplit(b, ",")), by=a]
```

This returns

```
    a  b
 1: a xx
 2: a yy
 3: a zz
 4: a zz
 5: a gg
 6: a tt
 7: b mm
 8: b nn
 9: c qq
10: c rr
11: c ss
12: c tt
```

Comment: I'm familiar with using 'by' for aggregation and reduction.  Interesting to see it employed for expansion. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks. I added a potentially more robust solution in the face of repeated IDs.

Comment: I don't find that the second half of this answer works as shown here. I am getting column `a` repeated a/b/c/a x3, not the pattern in above.

Comment: @moman822 You are right. I have corrected this to provide an implementation that will work for such a case.

Answer (score 1):

There is another method, but this method involves another package : splitstackshape.

```
library(splitstackshape)
cSplit(dt, "b", sep = ",", direction = "long")
   a  b
1: a xx
2: a yy
3: a zz
4: b mm
5: b nn
6: c qq
7: c rr
8: c ss
9: c tt
```

This function uses data.table to work. And this work even if we have multiple same value for the column "a".

Answer (score -2):

We can `split` the column 'b' by the delimiter ',' (using `strsplit`), grouped by 'a' and set the name of the new column i.e. 'V1' to 'b' with `setnames`

```
setnames(dt[, strsplit(b, ','), by = a], "V1", "b")[]
#   a  b
#1: a xx
#2: a yy
#3: a zz
#4: b mm
#5: b nn
#6: c qq
#7: c rr
#8: c ss
#9: c tt
```

---

If there are repeating elements in 'a' as in the below example

```
dt <- data.table(a = c('a','b','c', 'a'),
            b = c('xx,yy,zz','mm,nn','qq,rr,ss,tt', 'zz,gg,tt'))
```

we can group by the sequence of rows, do the `strsplit` on 'b', concatenate with the 'a' column and assign (`:=`) the 'grp' to NULL

```
dt[, c(a=a, b=strsplit(b, ",")), .(grp = 1:nrow(dt))][, grp := NULL][]
#    a  b
# 1: a xx
# 2: a yy
# 3: a zz
# 4: b mm
# 5: b nn
# 6: c qq
# 7: c rr
# 8: c ss
# 9: c tt
#10: a zz
#11: a gg
#12: a tt
```

NOTE: Both the methods are `data.table` methods